# Bloomberg .Net API - Response Data for Multiple Securities

Tags: c#, .net, bloomberg

Assuming that we are sending Bloomberg Historical data request for multiple securities using .Net API, is there any elegant way to separate/identify response data of each security?

I am aware that there is a field `sequenceNumber` in the response but not sure how it is mapped to each security.  My code snippet is given below.

```
Service refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("HistoricalDataRequest");
Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
securities.AppendValue("EURUSD CURNCY");
securities.AppendValue("USDJPY CURNCY");
securities.AppendValue("GBPUSD Curncy");
securities.AppendValue("USDCHF Curncy");

Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");                
fields.AppendValue("OPEN");
fields.AppendValue("HIGH");
fields.AppendValue("LOW");
fields.AppendValue("PX_LAST");

request.Set("periodicityAdjustment", "CALENDAR");  
request.Set("periodicitySelection", "DAILY");
request.Set("startDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
request.Set("endDate", Convert.ToString(null));

session.SendRequest(request, null);

while (true)
{
Event eventObj = session.NextEvent();
foreach (Message msg in eventObj.GetMessages()) 
{
    if (msg.MessageType.Equals(Name.GetName("HistoricalDataResponse")))
    {
        Element secDataArray = msg.GetElement("securityData");          
        Element securityData = secDataArray.GetElement(3);
        for (int index = 0; index < securityData.NumValues; index++)
        {
            Element fieldData = securityData.GetValueAsElement(index);
            Datetime time = fieldData.GetElementAsDate("date");
            decimal? open = fieldData.HasElement("OPEN") ? Convert.ToDecimal(fieldData.GetElementAsFloat64("OPEN")) : new decimal?();
            decimal? high = fieldData.HasElement("HIGH") ? Convert.ToDecimal(fieldData.GetElementAsFloat64("HIGH")) : new decimal?();
            decimal? low = fieldData.HasElement("LOW") ? Convert.ToDecimal(fieldData.GetElementAsFloat64("LOW")) : new decimal?();
            decimal? close = fieldData.HasElement("PX_LAST") ? Convert.ToDecimal(fieldData.GetElementAsFloat64("PX_LAST")) : new decimal?();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sequenceNumber` value that is returned corresponds to the order in which you added the securities with the call to `AppendValue`

```
securities.AppendValue("EURUSD CURNCY");  // Sequence number 1
securities.AppendValue("USDJPY CURNCY");  // Sequence number 2
securities.AppendValue("GBPUSD Curncy");  // Sequence number 3
securities.AppendValue("USDCHF Curncy");  // Sequence number 4
```

As per the [BLPAPI: Developer’s Guide](http://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/documentation/):

> Security sequence number, specifying the position of the security in the request.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying SequenceNumber logic. Is there any way apart from SequenceNumber, for example can we get the entire response of a security by SecurityName?

Comment: @RavinderSingh Why would you want to do that?  Comparing on ordinal is more efficient.

Comment: Yes agree. I implemented the solution the way you suggested and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

you may need one more loop:

```
foreach (Message msg in eventObj.GetMessages())
{
   Element element = msg.GetElement("securityData");

   for (int i = 0; i < element.NumValues; i++)
   {
      Element security = element.GetValueAsElement(i);
      string ticker = security.GetElementAsString("security");
      Element fields = security.GetElement("fieldData");
      decimal px_last  = Convert.toDecimal(fields.GetElementAsFloat64("PX_LAST"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java (easily transposable):

```
Element securityData = msg.getElement("securityData");
String ticker = securityData.getElementAsString("security");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the Bloomberg code from the `securityData` Element, like this:

```
string bloombergCode = secDataArray.GetElement("security").GetValueAsString();
```